# Uncaught Error: Row 29 has 1 columns, but must have 32

Tags: datatable, google-visualization, linegraph

I'm trying to get some CSV data into a DataTable in order to create a line graph. The CSV has gone through a function to clean up the data prior to creating a new DataTable, the variable **data2Array**.

I only want to access 5 of the columns from **data2Array**. When I try to add a new row with the 5 data values, I get the following exception:

```
Uncaught Error: Row 29 has 1 columns, but must have 32
```

This has me confused, because I can see I've only tried to add the one row to **data2Table**, supplying only the 5 aforementioned values. Here is the log of what the row looks like:

> 0, Jul 1 2015, 3.379, 6.57, 0

**data2Array** has 32 columns and 29 rows, but in my DataTable, I've only specified for 5 columns before attempting to add a row. Since I am not adding anything to the original data source, but rather to **data2Table**, why is the exception mentioning row 29 or needing 32 columns?  My new DataTable has been specified with only 5 columns.

Below is the code I am working with currently:

```
    var data2Array = fullDataArray(csvData2);
    console.log("data2 clean: " + data2Array);

    // request line graph - data2
    var data2Table = new google.visualization.DataTable(data2Array);
    data2Table.addColumn('number', 'colIndex');
    data2Table.addColumn('string', 'colLabel1');
    data2Table.addColumn('string', 'colLabel2');
    data2Table.addColumn('string', 'colLabel3');
    data2Table.addColumn('string', 'colLabel4');


    var testArr = [0, data2Array[0][0],data2Array[0][4], data2Array[0][5], data2Array[0][7]];
    console.log('test: ' + testArr);
    data2Table.addRow([0, data2Array[0][0],data2Array[0][4], data2Array[0][5], data2Array[0][7]]);
```

Comment: If you're adding completely new data into a new table structure, shouldn't the 'new' call at the var data2Table line be an empty initialization, rather than being constructed against data2Array?

ie, var data2Table = new google.visualization.DataTable();

Comment: I believe that's true, I've tested that, but I'm getting the same error :/

Comment: Are you certain that the data2Table.addrow() call is the one generating the exception? If anything, I would think the addrow() call would generate an exception about only having 5 columns, not 1 column.

Also, can you add the output of the two console.log statements?

Comment: first, @Paul is correct, there should be no arguments to the `DataTable` constructor, unless being initialized by JSON, [as found here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam) -- next, the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#data-format) for `LineChart` only allows the first column, the x-axis, to be a `'string'` column -- if you could please provide a sample of the data, before or after the conversion, it would be easier to diagnose the problem...

Comment: @WhiteHat Thanks for that -- I thought I had posted a follow-up to ask for the data -- but I must have forgotten it -- too many browser windows, not enough brain for them all.